# Are there any built-in modules for n-length integers in C#/C++/C?

Tags: c#, c++, c, long-integer, biginteger

In Python and a few other languages there are structs that allow for infinitely(if you have enough memory) long integers simply by adding more bits when needed, while in the C languages there seems to only be the most basic numeric types. Is there an implementation in C#/C++/C? So far haven't found any modules that allow n-length integers, but it could be I just was just looking in the wrong places.

Comment: Do you mean something like [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-7.0) in C#?

Comment: Please ask one question per post. The reasons for not having such a library in C, C++ and C# respectively might be quite different. In case of C, it doesn't come with a lot of standardised libs at all (not even a string one), so you'll have to use some 3rd party "big int" library.

Comment: To answer the question "Would it be difficult to implement such a concept in ..." - `Python` is a scripting language, which requires an `interpreter`. This `interpreter` is written in `C` and calls functions from `C` libraries. So the question itself doesn't make much sense. As anything what you write in `Python` is actually just gonna call functions from `C` libraries.

Comment: There are third-party libraries for that, for sure (like GMP). For the why it is not standard, I would answer that it **would have a very limited use case**, despite what beginners often think. I have been programming in C++ for 25 years and I never felt the need for this. Typically, either you need integers for counting discrete things or bytes, and 32-bit is already well enough (and 64-bit integers exist when not). Or you use `double` for other numbers, and their magnitude is not really limited. True, their precision have a limit, but this is enough for all practical usage I know of.

Comment: Also, I hope this is obvious, but big integers cannot be native to the hardware. CPU can handle 32-bit and 64-bit integers directly (sometimes even 128-bit). Floating point types `float` and `double` are also handled natively by modern processors. Hence their performance. Big integer support is necessary done by software and is therefore _orders of magnitude_ slower. In C and C++ the motto is: don't pay for what you don't need.

Comment: Mostly because C is, at its core, designed as a system programming language and C++ retains ability to do such development.  Few people doing such development need big integer types as much as beginners to C or C++ (particularly if they are used to interpreted or compiled-to-bytecode languages like Python) seem to believe.  A large number of Python implementations are based on the CPython VM, which is written in C, which sort-of demonstrates that C can be used to do such things.  Also, you haven't searched hard enough - there are certainly big integer libraries to be found, in both C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

Neither language natively supports variable-length integers.
There are third party librarys.. for example the GMP-Library in C++.